# Work With HashAlgorithm as an implementation of ICryptoTransform in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, hash, stream, cryptostream

According to Microsoft documentation, `HashAlgorithm` class implement `ICryptoTransform` interface, so we should be able to use it with `CryptoStream`. But when I use it, I get the input stream without any hashing. Where is my mistake?
My code is as following:

```
public static void HashFilesUsingCryptoStream(string inputPath)
        {
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPath);
            using ICryptoTransform hashAlg = SHA1.Create();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, hashAlg, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(fileBytes);
            var hashBytes = ms.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of Bytes in Hash algorithms: {hashBytes.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine("Hash: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashBytes));
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a `StreamWriter` to write to the `CryptoStream` (making sure that you `Dispose` the stream writer before going any further).  I'm guessing that someone needs to flush the stream after the write.  The `CryptoStream` example I'm looking at is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream

Comment: @Flydog Thanks. I tried it now and Yes, it works. I just changed the using (var cs=..) {} to old version of it and added the stream writer and it works! Where is the point in it?

Answer (score 0):

According to comment to the question, I can solve my problem as following (The difference is adding stream writer helper class and also disposing it right after writing the content to the stream.

```
public static void HashFilesUsingCryptoStream1(string inputPath)
        {
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPath);
            using ICryptoTransform hashAlg = SHA1.Create();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, hashAlg, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cs))
                writer.Write(fileBytes);//The stream must be closed first to ensure all data is computed and flushed.
            var hashBytes = ms.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of Bytes in Hash algorithms: {hashBytes.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine("Hash: " + Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes));
        }
```